# How can SQL UPDATE match more rows than similar SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql

The below SELECT query and UPDATE query has an identical FROM clause and WHERE clause.  As such, I expected the SELECT query to return the same number of rows which were matched and affected by the UPDATE query, but as seen, that is not the case.

I don't know whether it is related, but as seen by the update, I am attempting to save the record's username and email in another column, but as seen by the last query, I am not saving the email, just the username.

Why is this so?

```
mysql> SELECT p.old_username, p.username, p.old_email, u.email
    -> FROM users u INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = u.id INNER JOIN entities e ON e.id = p.id
    -> WHERE u.id =1753671666 AND u.id !=506836355 AND e.sites_id =2846702735;
+--------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| old_username | username   | old_email | email               |
+--------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| NULL         | myusername | NULL      | myemail@example.com |
+--------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> UPDATE
    -> users u INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = u.id INNER JOIN entities e ON e.id = p.id
    -> SET p.old_username = p.username, p.username = NULL,
    -> p.old_email = u.email, u.email = NULL,
    -> e.record_status = 'inactive', e.date_modified = NOW( ), e.modified_by_id =506836355
    -> WHERE u.id =1753671666 AND u.id !=506836355 AND e.sites_id =2846702735;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> SELECT p.old_username, p.username, p.old_email, u.email
    -> FROM users u INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = u.id INNER JOIN entities e ON e.id = p.id
    -> WHERE u.id =1753671666 AND u.id !=506836355 AND e.sites_id =2846702735;
+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+
| old_username | username | old_email | email |
+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+
| myusername   | NULL     | NULL      | NULL  |
+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Do you have a trigger on that table? Perhaps the trigger is changing 2 additional rows - e.g. in an auditing table or similar?

Comment: @RB.  Good idea.  Checked, and no triggers.

Comment: MySQL allows for updating multiple tables in a single statement?  I never knew that!

Comment: @RB.  `mysql> SHOW TRIGGERS;  Empty set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: @Brandon  Maybe not a good idea as I seem to get inconsistent results.  I will be posting another related question.

Comment: Yeah, that freaked me out a bit, too!  It wouldn't surprise me if that's confusing the record counts.

Comment: Maybe not using table alias,using real names? And writing it like "SET people.old_username....?

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz  I didn't think it would make a difference, but just to be sure, tested it and it did not.

Comment: Ok.... Sorry:( Just said because all the examples on mysql page were without aliases !! And maybe it was a problem ! . Ummmmm.....and entities table is being updated?

Comment: Could you please try this? 
UPDATE users AS u, people AS p, entities AS e
SET p.old_username = p.username,
      p.username = NULL,
      p.old_email = u.email, 
      u.email = NULL,
      e.record_status = 'inactive', e.date_modified = NOW( ),
      e.modified_by_id=506836355
     WHERE u.id =1753671666 
    AND u.id !=506836355 
    AND e.sites_id =2846702735
    AND p.id = u.id 
    AND e.id = p.id

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz  Same results.

Comment: I suppose the 3 records count should appear as @SteveBarron said, but the lines are also not being updated??? 
***** are you sure you have privileges over all the fields for updating ???
 The only idea I have apart from the privileges one,  is that maybe mysql is not doing the updates strictly as in written order... and that´s what is producing the data loss in some fields... is the entities table being updated???

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz Turned out MySQL doesn't have any defined order when updating multiple tables.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087318/order-of-precedence-of-update-on-multiple-table-update.  As such, wasn't updating the `users` table and the value stayed NULL.

Comment: @user1032531 :) it seems you´ll need to create a procedure... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SELECT statement is reporting that a single row is the result of the joined query.

But you are updating **3** tables:

```
p.old_username (and several others)
e.date_modified (and others)
u.email
```

Therefore there are 3 updates.

Comment: Okay, maybe that is why it says `3 rows affected`.  But the update also shows `Rows matched: 3`.  Maybe I never noticed before, but would not have expected this  I'll do some tests.

Comment: The easiest test might be to skip one of the table updates (like u.email) and see if it switches to 2 rows matched (it will almost certainly be 2 rows affected, to your point).

Comment: Steve,  I did your recommended tests and posted them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087318/order-of-precedence-of-update-on-multiple-columns.  What is more odd as now I seem to have only 2 rows affected on the query that shows three on this post.  I must be smoking something...

Comment: If I read that other post's SQL correctly, when you are updating only one table and it is (correctly) reporting only one record matched and affected.  

When you update columns in 2 tables, it reports 2.

That seems reasonable to me.