# Order of precedence of UPDATE on Multiple-table update

Tags: mysql

If I have an UPDATE statement where I am doing `SET p.old_email = u.email, u.email = NULL`, will `p.old_email = u.email` always happen before `u.email = NULL`?  The reason I ask is I am not witnessing such behavior.

```
mysql> SHOW TRIGGERS;
UPDATE
Empty set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
mysql> UPDATE
    -> users u INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = u.id INNER JOIN entities e ON e.id = p.id
    -> SET p.old_username = NULL, p.username = 'myusername',
    -> p.old_email = NULL, u.email = 'myemail@example.com',
    -> e.record_status = 'inactive', e.date_modified = NOW( ), e.modified_by_id =506836355
    -> WHERE u.id =1753671666 AND u.id !=506836355 AND e.sites_id =2846702735;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> SELECT p.old_username, p.username, p.old_email, u.email
    -> FROM users u INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = u.id INNER JOIN entities e ON e.id = p.id
    -> WHERE u.id =1753671666 AND u.id !=506836355 AND e.sites_id =2846702735;
+--------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| old_username | username   | old_email | email               |
+--------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| NULL         | myusername | NULL      | myemail@example.com |
+--------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> UPDATE
    -> users u INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = u.id INNER JOIN entities e ON e.id = p.id
    -> SET p.old_username = p.username, p.username = NULL
    -> WHERE u.id =1753671666 AND u.id !=506836355 AND e.sites_id =2846702735;
WHERE u.id =1753671666 AND u.id !=506836355 AND e.sites_id =2846702735Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec);

Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> SELECT p.old_username, p.username, p.old_email, u.email
    -> FROM users u INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = u.id INNER JOIN entities e ON e.id = p.id
    -> WHERE u.id =1753671666 AND u.id !=506836355 AND e.sites_id =2846702735;
+--------------+----------+-----------+---------------------+
| old_username | username | old_email | email               |
+--------------+----------+-----------+---------------------+
| myusername   | NULL     | NULL      | myemail@example.com |
+--------------+----------+-----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> UPDATE
    -> users u INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = u.id INNER JOIN entities e ON e.id = p.id
    -> SET p.old_email = u.email, u.email = NULL
    -> WHERE u.id =1753671666 AND u.id !=506836355 AND e.sites_id =2846702735;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> SELECT p.old_username, p.username, p.old_email, u.email
    -> FROM users u INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = u.id INNER JOIN entities e ON e.id = p.id
    -> WHERE u.id =1753671666 AND u.id !=506836355 AND e.sites_id =2846702735;
+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+
| old_username | username | old_email | email |
+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+
| myusername   | NULL     | NULL      | NULL  |
+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> UPDATE
    -> users u INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = u.id INNER JOIN entities e ON e.id = p.id
    -> SET p.old_username = NULL, p.username = 'myusername',
    -> p.old_email = NULL, u.email = 'myemail@example.com',
    -> e.record_status = 'inactive', e.date_modified = NOW( ), e.modified_by_id =506836355
    -> WHERE u.id =1753671666 AND u.id !=506836355 AND e.sites_id =2846702735;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> SELECT p.old_username, p.username, p.old_email, u.email
    -> FROM users u INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = u.id INNER JOIN entities e ON e.id = p.id
    -> WHERE u.id =1753671666 AND u.id !=506836355 AND e.sites_id =2846702735;
+--------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| old_username | username   | old_email | email               |
+--------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| NULL         | myusername | NULL      | myemail@example.com |
+--------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> UPDATE
    -> users u INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = u.id INNER JOIN entities e ON e.id = p.id
    -> SET p.old_username = p.username, p.username = NULL,
    -> p.old_email = u.email, u.email = NULL,
    -> e.record_status = 'inactive', e.date_modified = NOW( ), e.modified_by_id =506836355
    -> WHERE u.id =1753671666 AND u.id !=506836355 AND e.sites_id =2846702735;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> SELECT p.old_username, p.username, p.old_email, u.email
    -> FROM users u INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = u.id INNER JOIN entities e ON e.id = p.id
    -> WHERE u.id =1753671666 AND u.id !=506836355 AND e.sites_id =2846702735;
+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+
| old_username | username | old_email | email |
+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+
| myusername   | NULL     | NULL      | NULL  |
+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql>
```

Comment: Obviously you'd prefer to do it this way because you don't have to construct another update, but is there any other reason why you wouldn't simply perform two separate updates in order to do this?

Comment: @Neil Not really, but I would like to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html):

> The second assignment in the following statement sets col2 to the current (updated) col1 value, not the original col1 value. The result is that col1 and col2 have the same value. This behavior differs from standard SQL.

```
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
```

> Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order.

**You are performing multi-table updates, and the column assignments are not happening in a particular order as the documentation states.**

Comment: But as seen by the code I posted, `u.email` is not `NULL` before the update.

Comment: I don't see where your confusion is, everything looks fine to me.

Comment: Did you look at the SELECT query were I display `email`, and then the following query where I set `old_email=email`?  As seen, `email` is not NULL before the UPDATE query.  Doesn't look fine to me :(

Comment: `Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right.`  Ah, but it is not a Single-table UPDATE.  Maybe that is the problem!

Comment: Nice catch...you just answered the question :-)

Comment: Per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html, `Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order. `

Comment: Well, that had me for a loop!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you need to guarantee order, then do separate updates or maybe look into using a trigger.

Comment: Already changed it to a SELECT to get the current value, and then used that value in the UPDATE.

Comment: @user1032531 Beware of what you are doing.  It is possible that in between your `SELECT` and the `UPDATE` that someone else issued a `SELECT` and the values changed.  You should wrap everything in a single transaction.